# How do I debug MVC 3 web application?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, asp.net-mvc-3

I have an MVC 3 web application. I need to step through the controller code.
I set break point in the controller and hit F5. I get this error:
Unable to launch the ASP.NET development server because port 'xxxx' is in use.

Any one has the simple steps to help me step through the code?

Visual Studio: 2010
IIS: 7.5
OS: Win 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find this can happen if you had been working on an ASP.NET Website (MVC or Forms), and it has been starting the web development server. Then VS crashes and leaves it running. So as @ChrisF recommends, just make sure all the web dev servers are gone, then try again.

Specifically, the process name is either

`WebDev.WebServer40.exe`

or

`WebDev.WebServer20.exe`

This error is highly unlikely in an IIS hosted scenario.

Comment: I am not seeing any process like WebDev.*

Comment: Do you have permissions to open a port? Are you running as a very locked-down user?

Comment: I am admin on the machine (laptop)

Comment: Try running Visual Studio as an admin (right-click, run as admin). If that solves it, there's a command line you can run to permanently reserve that port address.

Comment: Cool, then this MSDN doc tells you how to make it accessible to your user, then you can avoid the UAC problems in the future. technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677364.aspx

Comment: Alternatively, you can turn off UAC (type UAC in start menu, pick the first option, slide the slider to the bottom).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the port is still in use from a previous execution of the application. Make sure that there are no instances of the Visual Studio web server running before you debug.

If you're using IIS to run the web site then you'll need to switch to using the Visual Studio web server or attach the debugger to the running process rather than hitting `F5`.

Comment: Chris, The app is running under IIS. What running process do I attach it to? I am not seeing any processes that says it .NET. Alternately how do I switch to use VS web server?

Comment: @Projapati - it's in the project settings.

Comment: I changed to Use Visual Studio Development Server and selected Auto-assign port. Still getting same port in use error.